# Hide Virtual Keyboard in on Chrome on Android

Tags: android, python, selenium-webdriver, adb, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way I can hide Soft Keyboar or Virtual Keyboard on Chrome on Android using Selenium or ChromeOptions or ADB.
I did some searching but all solution were like if the keyboard is open then press back button to hide it.
But is there a way to disable virtual keyboard from poping up during my entire execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to disable and enable keybords using `adb shell ime` commands. I wrote a Python script to enable/disable all keyboard inputs.

```
def enable_disable_android_input_methods(action):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "devices"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    while line:
        log.info(line)
        if re.match("\S+\s+device", line):
            break
        line = p.stdout.readline()
    else:
        raise AssertionError, "Device not connected via USB"
    p = subprocess.Popen("adb shell ime list -a".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    while line:
        m = re.search("mId=(.*)", line)
        if m:
            if action.lower() == 'enable':
                log.info("Enabling Keyboard layout: %s" % line)
                cmd = "adb shell ime enable %s" % m.group(1)
            else:
                log.info("Disabling Keyboard layout: %s" % line)
                cmd = "adb shell ime disable %s" % m.group(1)
            q = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = q.communicate()
            log.info(out)
        line = p.stdout.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to hide keyboard

```
 public void hideKeyboard() {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is again like if the keybord is present hide that, I am looking for a way so that keyboard doesn't pop up at all

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this in oncreate

this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```